# Exchange/Outlook 2010, C# SenderEmailAddress extra characters appended to name

Tags: c#, active-directory, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

So my question is what is 58D at the end of this string or 7F9 at the end of the next string?

Also, the extra characters are the same for each user. This only started happening when migrated to Exchange 2010.

```
Console.write(Message.SenderEmailAddress);
```

prints: /O=john doe/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP ()/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=john doe58D // <-- 58D look at this

```
Console.write(Message.SenderEmailAddress);
```

prints: /O=jane doe/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP ()/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=jane doe7F9 // <-- 7F9 or this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an encoded character. I'm not sure where you're getting the data from but that's the recipient's legacyExchangeDN value - Outlook and Exchange use it for various things under the covers.

Comment: Do you know some place where we can find it documented ?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I figured it was an encoded character. The problem is how to remove it. Can I trust that there is always going to be 3 characters there?

Comment: No I don't think you can reasonably expect that it's always there.